# Protecting Python scripts for ArcGIS DEsktop

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool

I created a custom toolbox in ArcGIS to add new Python scripts to be used by multiple persons.

When I save the tool box and the add it to their ArcToolbox they can edit the source code and the parameters.

How can I hide it or make it inaccessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed the code in the tool.  Here is a link to some ESRI information on how to embed your script to protect the code.
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/sharing-workflows/embedding-scripts-and-password-protecting-tools.htm